# how to get a variable value in select command and redirected to a file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am bit new in powershell and experiencing one problem and description is as follows:
I am having one file in which there are server names i want to check for connection with port number and also want to redirect output to a file (i want to append data). If connection is successful or unsuccessful i want to write output to file. I am using below code to do that and there is one customized variable which i also want to write in file.

```
 $server = Get-Content ('C:\my\dir\srv.txt')

 Foreach ($s in $server)
 
 {  $result = (Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s).TcpTestSucceeded

        If(!$Result){
                $Remark = "TCP connect to computer Successful"
                Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s | select TcpTestSucceeded,ComputerName,RemoteAddress,$Remark| Out-File status.txt

            }

            Else{ $Remark= "WARNING: TCP connect to computer either failed or timeout"

                Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s | select TcpTestSucceeded,ComputerName,RemoteAddress,$Remark | Out-File status.txt    

            }

       }
```

out file status.txt should be like this. I don't mind capturing this information in two different files as well, one for true and one for false TcpTestSucceeded

```
TcpTestSucceeded ComputerName RemoteAddress Remark 
---------------- ------------ ------------- ------------
            True VAFIC81-123   172.0.0.64  TCP connect to computer Successful
            False VAFIC81-678   172.0.0.64  WARNING: TCP connect to computer either failed or timeout
```

Comment: as an aside ... instead of using `Out-File` and getting a "dumb" plain text file, have you thot about using `Export-CSV` to get a structured text file? that would make using the data later MUCH easier since you could import it into various things _with meaning and structure_ instead of having to parse the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no reason to execute `Test-NetConnection` multiple times like this.  Once per server should be enough.

```
$server = Get-Content 'C:\my\dir\srv.txt'

$tcpTest = foreach ($s in $server) {
    # maybe you would also not wish to see warnings.
    # in that case add '-WarningAction SilentlyContinue' aswell
    $result = Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $remark = if ($result.TcpTestSucceeded -eq $true) {
                "TCP connect to computer Successful"
              }
              else {
                "WARNING: TCP connect to computer either failed or timeout"
              }
    # output as object with added property 'Remark' to be collected in variable '$tcpTest'
    $result | Select-Object TcpTestSucceeded,ComputerName,RemoteAddress,
                            @{Name = 'Remark'; Expression = {$remark}}
}

# output on screen
$tcpTest | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file
$tcpTest | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\my\dir\status.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a calculated property for this:

```
$server = Get-Content ('C:\my\dir\srv.txt')

 Foreach ($s in $server)
 
 {  $result = (Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s).TcpTestSucceeded

        If(!$Result){
                $Remark = "TCP connect to computer Successful"
                Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s | select TcpTestSucceeded,ComputerName,RemoteAddress,@{n="Remark";e={$Remark}} | Out-File status.txt

            }

            Else{ $Remark= "WARNING: TCP connect to computer either failed or timeout"

                Test-NetConnection -Port 443 -ComputerName $s | select TcpTestSucceeded,ComputerName,RemoteAddress,@{n="Remark";e={$Remark}} | Out-File status.txt    

            }

       }
```

A calculated property creates a custom property in Select-Object. It uses a hashtable where n is the header and e is the Expression.

Comment: In my case, I have similar script which is working perfectly without function but if I bind it inside the function (Ex:  function test { <script> }) So, it is failing for one of my dynamic server.